# Добавление к ebp

Tags: ассемблер, masm32, reverse-engineering

При реверсе файла вижу такую конструкцию:

```
mov     eax, offset aUser32_dll ; "USER32.dll"
add     eax, ebp
```

Не могу понять смысл.. зачем добавлять смещение строки к кадру стека?

Comment: По этим двум строкам ответить сложно. надо видеть все от точки входа в функцию, что бы понимать что находится на данный момент в ebp, где находится строка "user32.dll" в стеке или в куче. желательно так же видеть физические смещения указанные в инструкциях

Comment: Для начала, убедитесь что ebp - это и правда кадр стека. Иногда его используют в качестве еще одного регистра общего назначения.

Comment: Вы правы, регистр не используеться как кадр стека.